# Sharepoint document link in read-only mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, office-2010, office-2013

I have .docx files in a sharepoint library. When I open file by the link, it opens in read-only mode
BUT
I can click "Enable edit", edit this document and save it to the sharepoint library.

Can I set only "read-only" permissions for this file?
How can I use DispEx for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the library permissions to read only, so the user can pull a word doc from there, but not write to the library.  As far as a word doc itself goes, I don't think you can keep that in read only.  Once a user downloads a file, they can save it and edit it locally.. unless the word document is initially uploaded with some sort or protection.  Case in point, open Word (2010+), choose File, and choose Info.  There are various options in the Permissions section that should help you out.